# how make side navbar using razor in asp.net web app

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razorengine

i am tring to make the sidebar IN MY ASP.NET web app and using razor
here is what id looks now and i want to remove that white space between the end of the page and the side bar also what to make it collapse sidebar so the app is usable on mobile  here is the page :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSmd4.jpg

and here is the code and i am using bootstrap and razor in asp.net mvc web app anyone can help i am stuck for two days tell

```
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
               <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                   <li class="dropdown">
                       <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                           Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
                       </a>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                           <li class="divider"></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                       </ul>
                   </li>
                   <li><a href="~/Views/chapter/Create.cshtml">Profile</a></li>
                   <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Disabled</a></li>

               </ul>
           </div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

here is the main _layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/classRoom/Primary" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Primary <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Primary_One">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Primary_Two">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Primary_Three">Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Primary_Four">Four</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Primary_Five">Five</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Primary_Six">Six</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/classRoom/Primary" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Preparatory <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Preparatory_One">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Preparatory_Two">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Preparatory_Three">Three</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/classRoom/Primary" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Secondary <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Secondary_Two">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Secondary_Two">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/subject/select/Secondary_Three">Three</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>

                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>

                    @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Add Chapter", "newChapter", "chapter")</li>
                    }






                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />


        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

it will be great if someone tell me how to make one like this website
http://www.w3schools.com/
it is just everything i need thanks

Comment: Are you using `_Layout.cshtml` - if so show that too.

Comment: i have upload the layout page

Comment: @JamesP i did not get you in which page you are taking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_Layout.csthml` change HTML from this:

```
 <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The `container` div is what is preventing the full width. Keep your `View` the same but without the `<body>` tags as these should really stay in the Layout.

**Edit:**

To hide side bar on mobile screen you can surround sidebar markup with `<div class="hidden-xs">`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hidden-xs">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="~/Views/chapter/Create.cshtml">Profile</a></li>
                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Disabled</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Basic panel
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change the `col-xs-12` value on visible content as required.

Comment: if i want to make for only one page , the other pages doesn't have sidebar

Comment: Can you explain, the sidebar is in the View markup so will only be rendered for that View.

Comment: when i remove the <div class="container body-content"> in the layout it affected the hole website and i want that change affect one view only

Comment: i have made anther layout and make that view use that one it works thanks  do you have and idea how to make it collapse